# Getting crash issue in Platinum SDK after integration into an app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have integrated Platinum SDK in iOS app ([link](https://github.com/MediaBrowser/MediaBrowser.Plugins/blob/master/ThirdParty/UPnP/Platinum/README.txt)). I am able to turn iPhone into DLNA Server but getting crash issue in the following code. Could you please tell me what is wrong? One thing is that in case if I run the original project I am not getting any errors.Getting crash after integrate the Platinum SDK in the app. Thank you for your time.

File Name : `PltMediaserver.cpp`

Function is :

```
NPT_Result 
PLT_MediaServer::OnBrowseDirectChildren(PLT_ActionReference&          action, 
                                        const char*                   object_id, 
                                        const char*                   filter,
                                        NPT_UInt32                    starting_index,
                                        NPT_UInt32                    requested_count,
                                        const char*                   sort_criteria,
                                        const PLT_HttpRequestContext& context) 
{ 
    if (m_Delegate) {
        return m_Delegate->OnBrowseDirectChildren(action,
                                                  object_id, 
                                                  filter, 
                                                  starting_index, 
                                                  requested_count, 
                                                  sort_criteria, 
                                                  context);
    }
    return NPT_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED;
}
```